# pygame: Bouncing rocket

Tags: python, pygame

I am just learning how to use pygame.
But whenever I run the code, it doesn't run but a python rocket appears and starts bouncing.
The only thing I can do on the rocket is force quit.
My python is 3.8.2 and pygame is 1.9.6, on my mac, if it helps.
This is the code I'm trying to run, just a basic set up code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5
run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: If the python never ran, then how did the rocket appear in the first place?

Comment: I think he is referring to the python icon in the tray...

Comment: There's nothing in your code what would make anything move and the "rocket" bounce. On my system (Windows, Python 3.8.2, pygame 1.9.6) all that happens is that a motionless red rectangle appears.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code using python 3.7 on a macbook Mojave and I just got a red rectangle (like your code specifies) in one position. Possibly try restarting your computer, checking you version of python, or renaming the file (originally I named the file pygame and it was giving me a bunch of issues) to make it run the correct thing. 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jubin-  I just ran your code on Mac and it works.  I think the trouble is that IDLE won't allow it to run for some reason.

Try running it from the command line using Terminal app.  It runs fine for me doing that, but will not run from IDLE.

1. Open Terminal
2. Navigate your way to the folder that contains your file
3. Type "python filename.py"